# How can I change build action of a file (in UWP) that the user has picked from the storage after pressing a button?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10

The user has pressed a button to pick a file (e.g., a text file from his computer). I want to change its build action. Is is possible?

Comment: Could you explain what's mean of build action, Is it Visual Studio file build action?

Comment: Yes, this is Visual Studio file build action.
There is a UWP app I am working on.
I want user to pic a file from the system storage. But I also want to change its build action to "Content"

Comment: After add the file, you could open file's property then edit the build action manually.